# How to Show Images from File System with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Okay, so I have a database that stores the name of an uploaded file in a column called **filename**.

I am trying to use PHP to show that file (stored in the file-system, not database) by taking the filename as stored in the database and concatenating it onto the  HTML tag, like so:

```
$stmt = $db->dbh->query("SELECT id, filename FROM images");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

$path = '';

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $path = 'i/' . $row['filename'];
    echo "<img src=" . $path . "/>";
}
```

However, it's not showing anything.  What am I doing wrong, or what is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the image file name.  Try this:

```
  echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($path) . '"/>";
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much!  Is it okay if I did htmlspecialchars($row['filename']) instead of passing $path to that?